# Plist Error: String is Empty

Tags: php, xml, string, plist, syntax-error

I've created a PHP application to output a plist to bridge the gap between a database and an app.

The decision was made to use a plist as opposed to a sqlite database in the app above me so I must find a way to make this work.

I try and open the plist in x-code and it tells me that it's corrupt.

So I ran the console command:

```
sudo plutil ./filename.plist
```

This said 'Conversion of string failed. The string is empty'.

So i opened the plist in a text editor and did a search for `<string></string>` (denoting an empty string) which brought up no results. So I'm unsure what's wrong with it!

Can you help me?

I need a way to debug and figure out where the error is, but there doesn't seem a simple way to debug a plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm posting the solution here because this error practically killed me and it'd be great if someone could find the below solution helpful.

Basically, the database contains thousands of entries, so it was nigh-on impossible to debug each entry for erroneous characters.

I used PlistEdit Pro and copy/pasted the raw xml of the plist into it.
This worked.

What I think was happening is that the database outputted some criminals (dodgy characters), and my use of the PlistEdit Pro escaped these characters appropriately so it didn't break in X-Code.